# I am getting a TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given but I pass in two parameters

Tags: python, deep-learning

I am having trouble with training my model. frames is a dictionary with two key-value pairs of 2d arrays. I have tried putting in the whole dictionary and one element into the model, but it still does not work. Please let me know any suggestions

Here is my model:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        # Frames Input
        self.frames_inp = nn.Identity()

        # Embedding
        self.embedding = Embedding()

        # Encoder Transformer Blocks
        self.encoder = Encoder(NUM_BLOCKS_ENCODER)

        # Decoder
        self.decoder = Decoder(NUM_BLOCKS_DECODER)

        # Classifier
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Dropout(CLASSIFIER_DROPOUT_RATIO),
            nn.Linear(UNITS_DECODER, N_UNIQUE_CHARACTERS),
            nn.Softmax(dim=-1),
        )

    def forward(self, frames):
        # Frames
        x = self.frames_inp(frames)

        # Embedding
        x = self.embedding(x, frames)

        # Encoder Transformer Blocks
        x = self.encoder(x, frames)

        # Decoder
        x = self.decoder(x, phrase)

        # Classifier
        outputs = self.classifier(x)

        return outputs

# Create PyTorch Model
model = Model()

# Loss Function with Label Smoothing
loss_fn = scce_with_ls

# Adam Optimizer with weight decay
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), weight_decay=1e-5)

# TopK Metrics
metrics = [
    TopKAccuracy(1),
    TopKAccuracy(5),
]

# Loss Weights
loss_weights = None

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model = model.cuda()
```

Here is the code I am having trouble with:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset

# Define a custom dataset class
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X, y):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        inputs = {
            'frames': self.X[idx],
            'phrase': self.y[idx],
        }
        outputs = self.y[idx]
        return inputs, outputs

# Instantiate your custom dataset
train_dataset = CustomDataset(X_train, y_train)

# Instantiate the DataLoader with your custom dataset and batch size
train_dataloader = DataLoader(
    train_dataset,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    shuffle=True,  # Set to True for training to shuffle the data
    num_workers=0  # Increase this if you want to use multiple CPU cores for data loading
)

# Iterate through the data in batches
for batch in train_dataloader:

    # Unpack the batch into frames and phrase
    frames, phrase = batch
    print(f'frames {frames["frames"]}')
    print(f'phrase {len(phrase)}')

    # Forward pass to get the predictions
    outputs = model(frames)

    # Convert the predictions to numpy array and append to the list
    predictions.append(outputs.cpu().numpy())
    
    # Concatenate all predictions into a single numpy array
y_pred = np.concatenate(predictions, axis=0)

print(f'# NaN Values In Predictions: {np.isnan(y_pred).sum()}')
```

Here is my error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [39], in <cell line: 33>()
     38 print(f'phrase {len(phrase)}')
     40 # Forward pass to get the predictions
---> 41 outputs = model(frames['frames'])
     43 # Convert the predictions to numpy array and append to the list
     44 predictions.append(outputs.cpu().numpy())

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

Input In [33], in Model.forward(self, frames)
     29 x = self.frames_inp(frames)
     31 # Embedding
---> 32 x = self.embedding(x, frames)
     34 # Encoder Transformer Blocks
     35 x = self.encoder(x, frames)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Hint: where the code says `model = Model()`, that **worked**, right? But if you look at the `__init__` method that will be called, it has a `self` parameter, right? Where do you suppose the argument for that came from? Do you see how that would apply to other methods, too?

Comment: Where the code says `x = self.frames_inp(frames)`, what do you think this means? Specifically, what do you think will end up as `x`, and why is that `x` result useful? How do you think it should be used in the next part of the code, and why?

Answer (score 0):

The error is one of the modules in your `forward` - the embedder should be passed the embedded frames (you're passing the embeddings and the original inputs), i.e. something like:

```py
def forward(self, frames):
    # Frames
    x = self.frames_inp(frames)

    # Embedding
    x = self.embedding(x)

    # Encoder Transformer Blocks
    x = self.encoder(x)

    # Decoder
    x = self.decoder(x)

    # Classifier
    outputs = self.classifier(x)

    return outputs
```

I'm not sure where `phrases` came from - I suspect that's wrong as well.

Also, it's worth noting that the error message is slightly misleading because Python considers `self` as a positional argument. So when it says you supplied 3 positional arguments when two are required it means you supplied two arguments when one was required (since self is automatically supplied)